# Dynamic TabBar and TabBarView with REST API data: Flutter

Tags: flutter, rest, tabs, tabbar, flutter-futurebuilder

I am working on a Flutter Application in which I am fetching data from the REST APIs.
**My case-**
The screen consists of a top **TabBar** which contains a dynamic number of tabs depending on the number of topics fetched from a REST API (These topics will be available before showing the tabs). Below the TabBar, there will be a TabBarView for each of the tabs and associated data should be fetched when a particular Tab is selected (This data should be fetched only when the tab is selected).
Here is a sample image-
[image]

Now the part of screen which is is in bluegrey color will be used to show a list of REST API responses. This will be dynamically fetched when the tab is selected.

```
 return Scaffold(
        appBar: _appBar,
        body: Consumer<CategoryProvider>(
          builder: (context, categoryProvider, child) {
            if (categoryProvider.subscribedCategories == null ||
                categoryProvider.subscribedCategories.isNotEmpty) {
              return DefaultTabController(
                
                length: categoryProvider.subscribedCategories.length,
                initialIndex: 0,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: height * 0.05,
                      child: TabBar(
                        labelColor: Colors.red,
                        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.green,
                        tabs: _tabsList(categoryProvider.subscribedCategories),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: height * 0.95,
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.blueGrey,
                          height: height * 0.95,
                          child: TabBarView(
                            children: _tabs.map((Tab tab) {
                              final String label = tab.text!.toLowerCase();
                              return Center(
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 100,
                                  width: 100,
                                  child: Text(
                                    'This is the $label tab',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15.sp,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            } else
              return Center(
                child: Text(
                  'You haven\'t subscribed to any topic yet',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15.sp,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  ),
                ),
              );
          },
        )
);
```

Please help me find a way by which I can achieve this same screen. (I have attached code, I am using)